# How do I import dependencies in a WebExtension?

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, firefox-addon-webextensions, content-script

I'm try to develop a web extension and I figured that importing dependencies would be no different to any other javascript project. For example I'm using a package called languagedetect which install normally as such:

`npm install languagedetect --save`

(It then appears in the package.json)

but then my content script looks like the following:

```
var LanguageDetect = require('languagedetect')
var lngDetector = new LanguageDetect()
console.log(lngDetector.detect('This is a test.'))
```

and it fails to print anything.

The debug output isn't very informative either:

```
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "_rotOffS"  createjs-2015.11.26.min.js:17:26988
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  www.google.de:52:964
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "0.6605486166848867"  www.google.de:1:1382
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  www.google.de:113:42
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  www.google.de:113:65
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  www.google.de:137:669
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  www.google.de:188:267
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  www.google.de:216:119
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  www.google.de:280:288
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  www.google.de:308:415
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  www.google.de:323:177
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  www.google.de:334:142
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  www.google.de:355:235
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "ActiveXObject"  www.google.de:221:470
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property 2  www.google.de:317:60
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property 6  www.google.de:34:311
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "t"  www.google.de:400:323
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "tick"  www.google.de:106:417
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "closure_lm_783901"  www.google.de:114:497
ReferenceError: require is not defined  content-script.js:2:5
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  snowgames_bobsled18.2.js:16:491
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  snowgames_bobsled18.2.js:19:285
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  snowgames_bobsled18.2.js:39:37
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  snowgames_bobsled18.2.js:39:60
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  snowgames_bobsled18.2.js:48:368
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  snowgames_bobsled18.2.js:66:14
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  snowgames_bobsled18.2.js:76:35
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "closure_lm_529465"  snowgames_bobsled18.2.js:40:313
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "touchend"  snowgames_bobsled18.2.js:35:643
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "R"  snowgames_bobsled18.2.js:43:754
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "readystatechange"  snowgames_bobsled18.2.js:43:34
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:84:99
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:123:234
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:123:253
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:125:15
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:125:39
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:137:75
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:212:194
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:226:466
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:228:114
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:239:314
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:367:150
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:369:190
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:396:65
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:398:117
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:433:456
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:453:66
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:476:411
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:476:455
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:477:37
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:485:166
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:489:98
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:524:438
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:556:894
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:566:178
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:567:68
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:575:350
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:576:63
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:576:150
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:625:26
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:628:480
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:642:177
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:649:337
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:661:41
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:661:54
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:665:323
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:680:121
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:681:64
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:701:448
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:705:39
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:758:120
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:763:125
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:802:275
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:841:108
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:843:495
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:845:463
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:890:70
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:894:225
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:936:329
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:936:470
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:1124:566
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:1140:278
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:1141:181
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:1183:150
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:1299:382
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:1398:416
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:1411:186
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:1412:57
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:1412:364
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "closure_lm_80732"  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:126:293
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "pageshow"  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:118:451
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "active"  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:250:241
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "setImmediate"  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:187:120
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "i"  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:37:281
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "t-aTz9-_sUcEc"  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:1353:210
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "load"  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:398:83
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "ma"  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:934:146
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "refspre"  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:937:49
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property 57  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:625:93
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property 230  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:626:53
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "Ga"  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:803:225
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "Ea"  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:919:485
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "Wa"  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:922:147
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "dg"  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:661:210
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "Ea"  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:847:34
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:63:172
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:117:675
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:136:378
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:202:456
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:353:463
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:366:100
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:425:433
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:482:64
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:526:317
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:592:233
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:615:288
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:618:213
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:696:47
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "uE"  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:494:21
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:56:185
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:56:252
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:65:404
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:74:191
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:95:153
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:101:140
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:147:402
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:160:263
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:194:151
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:208:17
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:221:415
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:234:208
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:234:302
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:249:167
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:268:108
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:271:329
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:286:351
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:289:222
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:291:172
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:308:341
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "_c"  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:94:392
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "t"  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:100:85
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  cb=gapi.loaded_0:59:151
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  cb=gapi.loaded_0:178:98
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  cb=gapi.loaded_0:178:111
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  cb=gapi.loaded_0:190:168
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  cb=gapi.loaded_0:273:123
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  cb=gapi.loaded_0:275:175
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  cb=gapi.loaded_0:324:223
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  cb=gapi.loaded_0:325:383
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  cb=gapi.loaded_0:329:378
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  cb=gapi.loaded_0:330:464
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  cb=gapi.loaded_0:332:75
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  cb=gapi.loaded_0:358:155
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "push"  cb=gapi.loaded_0:61:469
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "push"  cb=gapi.loaded_0:142:169
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "disableForceSecure"  cb=gapi.loaded_0:235:166
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "useLegacyProtocol"  cb=gapi.loaded_0:242:367
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "startE"  cb=gapi.loaded_0:337:363
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "OV"  cb=gapi.loaded_0:367:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "googleapis"  rs=AA2YrTtMoJJMGQfOfYZyZ7reaiaiva99OQ:289:112
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "button"[Learn More]  utilityOverlay.js:148:16
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "relatedTarget"  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:114:159
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  react-intl.js:8:341
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  react-intl.js:8:23093
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  react-intl.js:8:27029
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "[object Object]"  activity-stream.bundle.js:1662:68
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "initialNow"  react-intl.js:9:1884
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "$$typeof"  react-dom.js:15:19504
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "value"  react-dom.js:12:29378
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "checked"  react-dom.js:12:29456
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property 0  activity-stream.bundle.js:751:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "type"  activity-stream.bundle.js:3231:11
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property 1  snowgames_bobsled18.2.js:68:280
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "delta"  createjs-2015.11.26.min.js:14:1041
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "mode"  createjs-2015.11.26.min.js:14:682
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "path"  createjs-2015.11.26.min.js:12:21607
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "visibilitychange"  rs=ACT90oHF8CehQzZYBmLRg-lPV1PUQuqVpg:135:36
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "componentDidUpdate"  react-dom.js:13:9781
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "type"  activity-stream.bundle.js:2207:47
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "children"  activity-stream.bundle.js:2736:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "_self"  react.js:12:11225
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "_defaultEngine"  contentSearchUI.js:76:5
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "_firstSession"  onboarding.js:887:1
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  react-intl.js:8:341
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  react-intl.js:8:23093
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?  react-intl.js:8:27029
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "[object Object]"  activity-stream.bundle.js:1662:68
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "initialNow"  react-intl.js:9:1884
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "$$typeof"  react-dom.js:15:19504
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "value"  react-dom.js:12:29378
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "checked"  react-dom.js:12:29456
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property 0  activity-stream.bundle.js:751:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "type"  activity-stream.bundle.js:3231:11
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "componentDidUpdate"  react-dom.js:13:9781
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "type"  activity-stream.bundle.js:2207:47
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "children"  activity-stream.bundle.js:2736:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "_self"  react.js:12:11225
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "_defaultEngine"  contentSearchUI.js:76:5
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "_firstSession"  onboarding.js:887:1
TypeError: setting getter-only property "maxRows"[Learn More]  autocomplete.xml:1012:11
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "@mozilla.org/network/protocol/about;1?what=debug"[Learn More] E10SUtils.jsm:28:5
TypeError: setting getter-only property "maxRows"[Learn More] autocomplete.xml:1012:11
NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI: Component returned failure code: 0x804b000a (NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI) [nsIWebNavigation.loadURIWithOptions]  browser-child.js:359
TypeError: setting getter-only property "maxRows"[Learn More]  autocomplete.xml:1012:11
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?[Learn More]  react-dom.js:6702:48
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?[Learn More]  react-dom.js:10515:47
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)?[Learn More]
```